# Invalid column name while updating table, split entity

Tags: mapping, entity-framework-5

When i try to SaveChanges() to insert a new entity, I get the following exception.

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException : An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  ----> System.Data.UpdateException : An error occurred while updating the entries. See     the inner exception for details.
  ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Invalid column name 'LD_Content'.
Invalid column name 'LD_File'.
```

I'm not using Code First nor Database First approach here. The database is preexisting, but the entity code is generated from custom templates.

These are the DB tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Licences](
    [L_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Licences] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [L_ID] ASC
))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Licences]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Licences_LicenceData] FOREIGN KEY([L_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[LicenceData] ([LD_ID])
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LicenceData](
    [LD_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [LD_Content] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [LD_File] [varbinary](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LicenceData] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [LD_ID] ASC
))
```

These are the entities:

```
[Table("Licences")]
public class Licence
{
    [Required, Display(Name="ID"), Column("L_ID")]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public virtual LicenceFile File { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Content"), Column("LD_Content")]
    public virtual string Content { get; set; }
}


[Table("LicenceData")]
public class LicenceFile
{
    [Required, Display(Name = "ID"), Column("LD_ID")]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "File"), Column("LD_File")]
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Licence>()
    .Map(m =>
    {
    m.Properties(licence => new {licence.Content});
    m.ToTable("LicenceData");
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Licence>().HasRequired(i => i.File).WithRequiredPrincipal();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

The entity is created with its navigation property set:

```
 new Licence
 {
    Content = "content",
    File = new LicenceFile()
 }
```

Summing up, there are two tables in one-to-one relationship. One of the entities, Licence, maps to its table (Licences) and also to one of the columns of the other table (entity splitting). The second entity, LicenceFile, maps to the ramaining columns of the other table (LienceData).

What has gone wrong here?